# Command line application install using GoLang

Tags: go

I'm not sure how this would work but I'm basically trying to write a command line app that I can run commands and subcommands from.  I'm using this popular third party library for parsing command line parameters:

https://github.com/urfave/cli

My problem is I have a project folder where my .go files will live:

```
MyProject
```

so even if in the code in my main.go file, using their example, I have:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"

  "github.com/urfave/cli"
)

func main() {
  app := cli.NewApp()
  app.Name = "greet"
  app.Usage = "fight the loneliness!"
  app.Action = func(c *cli.Context) error {
    fmt.Println("Hello friend!")
    return nil
  }

  app.Run(os.Args)
}
```

when I run `go install`,

in my $GOPATH/bin directory, I actually get MyProject built.  And then when I run `MyProject` from the terminal, I get

```
USAGE:
myproject [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]
```

But in reality, I don't need the `myproject` command first.  Is there a way this is normally done with command line apps or third party packages to create command line apps so that I can run `greet` from the command line instead of `myproject` as the first command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation for the [go build command](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)

```
go build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]
```

> When compiling a single main package, build writes the resulting
>   executable to an output file named after the first source file ('go
>   build ed.go rx.go' writes 'ed' or 'ed.exe') or the source code
>   directory ('go build unix/sam' writes 'sam' or 'sam.exe'). The '.exe'
>   suffix is added when writing a Windows executable.
>
> When compiling multiple packages or a single non-main package, build
>   compiles the packages but discards the resulting object, serving only
>   as a check that the packages can be built.
>
> The -o flag, only allowed when compiling a single package, forces
>   build to write the resulting executable or object to the named output
>   file, instead of the default behavior described in the last two
>   paragraphs.

Try building it like this `go build -o greet` and do not forget to add the resulting executable to your `$PATH` if you want it to be accessible from everywhere.

---

Alternatively, you can just 1) create an alias; or 2) symlink to the actual executable:

1. `alias greet='myproject'`
2. `ln -s $GOPATH/bin/myproject greet` (the link will be created in the current dir)